# Navigate client-side or server-side file system in Shiny to select folder

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to allow users of my app to navigate either the file system on their computer or a specific volume on the hosting server.  ShinyFiles allows for a connection to the server, but is there a way to allow Shiny to access a directory on the user's computer when not run locally?  It would be great to have a selectable UI element that would give the choice of which file system to look in. This could be similar to how the shinyDirChoose function behaves when passing multiple "roots" in, allowing selection of different parts of the folder structure.  I would like to be able to select a whole directory, not just single files if possible.

Here is a reproducible example that shows the directory navigation portion of my app.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  shinyDirButton(id='directory', label='Folder select', title='Please select a folder'),
  
  column(1, offset = 11, 
         actionButton("exitButton", "Exit")), #kill the app
  
  mainPanel(
    tags$h4("Folder selected: ", verbatimTextOutput("directorypath")), # print out the path of the selected folder
    width = 8),
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  volumes <- c(Home = fs::path_home())
  shinyDirChoose(input=input, id="directory", roots = volumes, session = session, restrictions = system.file(package = "base"))
  
  output$directorypath <- renderPrint({
    if (is.integer(input$directory)) {
      cat("No directory has been selected")
    } else {
      cat(parseDirPath(roots=volumes, selection=input$directory))
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$exitButton, {
    stopApp()
  })
  
})


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Use Upload or Download buttons to interact with user file system

Comment: Great thanks. I do have a need to upload specific files, so I will use Shiny's fileInput function for that.  Do you know if it is possible to get the directory path information from the client side?  This would effectively serve as the working directory in the app's server code.

Comment: The app server writes on the server's file system. Then you can offer the user to download the files

Comment: That makes sense.  Users of my app will usually be uploading around 20 or more files and downloading over 100 files at times.  Would it be possible to pass the user's folder directory over to the server and have the server work directly from there?  This would save a lot of clicking.

Comment: You could use zip files as containers for both inputs and outputs. This would also save bandwidth

Comment: Okay cool I can look into building that in.  So far that does sound like the best option I have.  Thanks!